# Loading original images besides the transformed ones using ImageFolder

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a GAN to colorize images. For that, I'm using `ImageFolder` of `torchvision` to load grayscale images but I also need the original data alongwith the transformed ones.

I want it in the fastest way as the data is large. I want to make `ImageFolder` load both at the same time to reduce the time complexity.

```
def load_data_bw(opt):
    datapath = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/faces/2003'

    dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(datapath,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                                                    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3), #load images as grayscale with three channels
                                                    transforms.RandomChoice(
                                                       [transforms.Resize(opt['loadSize'], interpolation=1),
                                                        transforms.Resize(opt['loadSize'], interpolation=2),
                                                        transforms.Resize(opt['loadSize'], interpolation=3),
                                                        transforms.Resize((opt['loadSize'], opt['loadSize']),
                                                                          interpolation=1),
                                                        transforms.Resize((opt['loadSize'], opt['loadSize']),
                                                                          interpolation=2),
                                                        transforms.Resize((opt['loadSize'], opt['loadSize']),
                                                                          interpolation=3)]
                                                    ),
                                                    transforms.RandomChoice(
                                                       [transforms.RandomResizedCrop(opt['fineSize'], interpolation=1),
                                                        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(opt['fineSize'], interpolation=2),
                                                        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(opt['fineSize'], interpolation=3)]
                                                    ),
                                                    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.1, contrast=0.1),
                                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                                    transforms.ToTensor()
                                               ]))
    return dataset
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
for iteration, orig_data, gray_data in enumerate(training_data_loader, 1):
    # code..
```

Comment: Didn't you need a collate_fn()? I'm trying to do similar dataset like you but I could stack original and main datasets paired, I searched and started some topics in pytorch forums but I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have 2 dataset variables i.e. `dataset_bw` and `dataset_color` that you can load as you mention using `ImageFolder`. Then you could do the following :

```
class GAN_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset_bw, dataset_color):
        self.dataset1 = dataset_bw
        self.dataset2 = dataset_color

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x1 = self.dataset1[index]
        x2 = self.dataset2[index]

        return x1, x2

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset1)

dataset = GAN_dataset(dataset_bw, dataset_color)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = ...)
```

This way you when you iterate through `loader`, you will get two images as you require.

Comment: what should be the dataset_bw and dataset_color input? Dataloader or scikit image io should be used or just imagefolder will be enough? the point is that the images are paired with name, I mean the main and the colored are have same name, so the imagefolder will paire them?

Comment: Another thing is splitting and shuffling, the method you described can be used for shuffling and splitting for training and testing? ( I know that shuffling is not necessary for images in this case, but is it possible in case of some not common tasks?)

Comment: `dataset_bw` or `dataset_color` should be defined as OP has done in their question (using `ImageFolder`). Only then, it can be used by `DataLoader`. In the `dataset_bw` and `dataset_color`, don't use shuffle, then the images should be in the same order (same indices) as long as they have the same names. Later when you write the combined `GAN_dataset`, then you can use shuffle in the following `DataLoader` so that both will be shuffled together (otherwise you lose the pairing).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about splitting? is it possible in dataloader?

Comment: I am not sure. You could ask a new question or look for that online. I usually split my datasets beforehand (using Pandas or keeping in separate folders) i.e. before loading into the `Dataset`.