# Pytorch loading images and ground truth images for for training neural network

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to use custom image data for training and testing a pytorch neural network. I have a folder of images as data and another folder images as ground truth. Files and ground truth images have same name but they are in a separate folder. I want to use them as image and ground truth as pair, for example, 1.jpg feed to network and result of htis picture should compare with other 1.jpg(its ground truth). I want to my neural network output to be image not classification(like image to image translation or pix2pix).

I have tried pytorch dataloader and some other docs but they was not what I needed. Some docs I tried:

https://www.kaggle.com/leighplt/pytorch-tutorial-dataset-data-preparetion-stage

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-efficient-custom-datasets-in-pytorch-2563b946fd9f

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html

Comment: Try making 2 different `Dataset` objects using your 2 image folders, and then write a `DataLoader` that loads from both the `Dataset` objects. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520646/7615877)

Comment: I don't see why the dataloader class shouldn't fit your purpose. In addition to what @akshayk07 suggested you could also write a custom `Dataset` class that returns a dictionary or tuple containing your raw and ground truth image. You can also have a look at [gunpowder](http://funkey.science/gunpowder/index.html) which is a scalable, fast framework to load data.