# How to load multi-image input in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a dataset with 2 RGB images per data sample (6 channels). How to read such a dataset in PyTorch?

For one RGB  image I used:

```
data_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
mel_dataset_train = datasets.ImageFolder(root='./ftrain',
                                         transform=data_transform)
train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(mel_dataset_train)
dataset_loader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mel_dataset_train,
                                                   batch_size=64, shuffle=True, sampler=train_sampler,
                                                   num_workers=config.workers)
```

Yet I do not see how to modify it to read two images per data sample instead of one.

Comment: how are those 6-channel images stored in memory? That should help you find how to load them.

Comment: They are stored As image pairs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520646/7615877
This is my answer to a similar question where the user had 2 dataset variables and wanted to load them simultaneously. This should work for you as well. However, this assumes that image pairs are in separate folders but with same names for each pair. If that is not possible, then you'll have to write a custom Dataset class that loads the image pairs simultaneously in the `__get_item__` function.