# is there a way to shuffle multi dataloader in same order?

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there a way to shuffle each dataset equally when loading the dataset at once using each pytorch datataloder?

ex) facedata - face1, face2, face3, face4, maskdata - mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4

after call dataloader(facedata, shuffle=True), dataloader(maskdata, shuffle=True)

the result is same order face2, face3 and mask2, mask3

Comment: you should write a dataloader which processes both of them together and returns multi output

Comment: do you mean i should write custom dataloader or just use multi input for dataset parameter in one dataloader?

Comment: I believe they mean that you need to write a custom dataset class (which is the more correct term). You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520646/7615877) which does a similar thing.

Comment: yes, I meant pytorch dataset class

Comment: thx guys i made it